# Uploading data from Excel to Database (Access), using ADODB / DAO, checking data for correct input mask

Tags: excel, ms-access, dao, adodb, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA code, that would upload data to Access database using  ADODB connection. The problem is that I want to check data integrity before upload, so checking for input mask format, allowed values, whether field is required, length of field, type of data. So far what I figured out, I would

1. Let the user choose which database and what table to upload to (ADODB.OpenSchema)
2. Connect with DAO to get information about inputmask and other (at least input mask can be done only by DAO)
3. Connect to selected table, create empty recordset, disconnect (ADODB)
4. Test data to parameters while building batch recordset, and ignore lines with wrtong data
5. Upload data

**Is there other commonly used way to test data for inputmask format, before uploading to database? Just give me directions, i'll google rest**

See below what I have so far, if you are interested.

Thank you

```
 Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub opentest()

Dim file As String, table As String
Dim outputarray As Variant
Dim cancelwork As Boolean
Dim coll As Collection
Set coll = New Collection


Dim adSchemaTables As Long, adOpenDynamic As Long, adLockBatchOptimistic As Long, adUseClient As Long 'named methods/properties must be defined as numbers for late binding
adOpenDynamic = 2
adLockBatchOptimistic = 4
adSchemaTables = 20
adUseClient = 3




With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) 'lets user select database
    .Title = "Select Database"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            End
        Else
            file = CStr(.SelectedItems(1))
    End If

End With


Dim cnn As Object, rs As Object   ' late binding, should allow no need for ADO library reference in excel
Set cnn = createobject("ADODB.connection")
Set rs = createobject("ADODB.Recordset")

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & file & ";" & "Persist Security Info=False"

Set rs = cnn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables, Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, "link")) 'for linked tables

Do While Not rs.EOF
    coll.Add CStr(rs("table_name"))
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

Set rs = Nothing

Set rs = cnn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables, Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, "table")) 'for actual tables

Do While Not rs.EOF
    coll.Add CStr(rs("table_name"))
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

Call ListBox(coll, table) 'lets the user select table where to upload

Set rs = Nothing
Set rs = createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

rs.Open "select * from " & table & " where false", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic 'connection

Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing 'disconnecting to build data


Call dataload(rs, cancelwork) 'calling dataload function

If cancelwork = True Then
        Call closing(rs, cnn)
        End
End If


Set rs.ActiveConnection = cnn

rs.UpdateBatch 'uploading data



Call closing(rs, cnn)

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub closing(rs As Object, cnn As Object)


rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub ListBox(ByVal coll As Collection, ByRef table As String)

Dim item As Variant

For Each item In coll
    ListBoxForm.ListBox1.AddItem (item)
Next item

ListBoxForm.Show
table = ListBoxForm.ListBox1.value

ListBoxForm.ListBox1.Clear

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub dataload(ByRef rs As Object, ByRef cancelwork As Boolean)
Dim loadarray() As Variant
Dim region As Range
Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult

On Error Resume Next
Set region = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select data to upload", Type:=8)
If region Is Nothing Then
        End
End If

loadarray = region

If (UBound(loadarray, 2) - LBound(loadarray, 1) + 1) > rs.Fields.Count Then
        MsgBox "Number of columns to be uploaded is greater then number of columns in database, ending"
        cancelwork = True
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf (UBound(loadarray, 2) - LBound(loadarray, 1) + 1) < rs.Fields.Count Then
        response = MsgBox("Number of columns to be uploaded is less then number of columns in database", vbOKCancel)
        If response = vbCancel Then
                cancelwork = True
                Exit Sub
        End If
End If

Set rs = recordsetload(rs, loadarray, region)


End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function recordsetload(rs As Object, loadarray As Variant, region As Range) As Object

Dim rowi As Long, columni As Long, rsrow As Long

For rowi = LBound(loadarray, 1) To UBound(loadarray, 1)
        rs.AddNew
        For columni = LBound(loadarray, 2) To UBound(loadarray, 2)
                rs.Fields(columni - 1).value = loadarray(rowi, columni)
        Next columni
Next rowi

Set recordsetload = rs

End Function
```

---

```
    Sub daotry2()
    Dim file As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "Select Database"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show

        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
                End
            Else
                file = CStr(.SelectedItems(1))
        End If

    End With

    Dim db As Object  'late binding without reference, seems to work, but might cause trouble, not tested
    Dim tbl As Object

    Dim dbe As Object
    Set dbe = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")  'depends on win version


    Set db = dbe.OpenDatabase(file)
    Set tbl = db.TableDefs("CAPEX")

    Debug.Print tbl.Fields(0).Properties("InputMask")
    Debug.Print tbl.Fields(0).Properties("Size")
    Debug.Print tbl.Fields(0).Properties("ValidationRule")
    Debug.Print tbl.Fields(0).Properties("Required")

    db.Close

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So to me, it looks like you're making this unnecessarily complicated. I can't speak to what is the most common pattern, but when I did this, the approach I took was to have the code invisibly make a copy of the table I want to eventually append my data to, and try to insert the data into that staging table. Then if there were any errors, Access automatically makes a table with "ImportError" in the name which you can look through to identify the problems. You could write code to count the number of errors of each kind, and output that message to the user. If that ImportError table is not created, then you know there are no errors, so you can copy the data from your staging table into the final table, and delete the staging table.

The benefit of this approach is you don't have to have your code check the input masks and validation rules of the table you want to append to; you just *do it* and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Using Will Jobs method

By creating and using staging table I do not remove problem I have. If I try import data from Excel to Access, and there are data added to disconnected recordset that do not comply with table rules, by batch update still fails, and only imports some of the lines. I have no idea what was imported and what failed

Easiest approach I found was combination of "On error resume next" and updating each added line on it's own. If it does not follow the rules of table, it fails to update, and I can mark this line red in Excel.

Slight change to connection on adLockPesimistic (value 2), and no disconnection of recordset

```
rs.Open "select * from " & table & " where false", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPesimistic 'connection
```

And `recordsetload` was changed. It will add only lines that follow the table rules. Comparing batch update and single record update, on 661 lines 23 fields makes very little time difference (batch update seems to be consistently 1s slower on this amount of data)

```
Private Function recordsetload(rs As Object, loadarray As Variant, region As Range) As Object

Dim rowi As Long, columni As Long, rsrow As Long

Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next
For rowi = LBound(loadarray, 1) To UBound(loadarray, 1)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
                rs.AddNew
            Else
                Err.Clear
        End If
        For columni = LBound(loadarray, 2) To UBound(loadarray, 2)
                rs.Fields(columni - 1).value = loadarray(rowi, columni)
        Next columni
        rs.Update
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                region.Rows(rowi).Interior.colorindex = 3
        End If

Next rowi
On Error GoTo 0

Set recordsetload = rs

End Function
```